# NoReverseMatch from reverse() use in custom template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm using a custom template tag in my Django app. When attempting to call `reverse` to obtain a url, I receive a `NoReverseMatch` error, despite the same call working elsewhere in the app.

In `portal/templatetags/custom_tags.py`:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def breadcrumb(view, text, *args):
    return u'» <a href="' + reverse(view, args) + '">' + text + '</a>'
```

Inside a template:

`{% breadcrumb 'portal-home' 'Portal' %}`

In `portal/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    # home
    url(r'home/$', portal_home, name='portal-home'),
    ...
]
```

There is definitely a view named `portal-home` and when I attempt `reverse('portal-home')` elsewhere in the app (like in a view for example) it works fine.

Here is the exact error:

```
Reverse for 'portal-home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I forgot how to python. I needed to do:

`reverse(view, *args)`